# jokes played or cracked

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Which is the correct way to mention the idea of jokes played in a comedy serial:

> I enjoy watching my family members laughing at the jokes **cracked** in the soap opera.

or:

> I enjoy watching my family members laughing at the jokes **played** in the soap opera.

I was just describing the reason why I like to watch TV with my family members: So I had to choose any one of the above two sentences. The complete description that I used is as follows: I like to watch serial along with my family members as in this case we are able to relish it more. For instance, if we are watching a comedy serial then we enjoy by repeating the funny lines. I especially enjoy watching my family members laughing at the jokes cracked in the soap opera.

So, I know what the word means. I just need to know how to use it so it sounds natural.

Comment: I have never heard the expression "to watch serial" - in my experience the phrase would always be "watch serials" or "watch television", but this may be highly region- and dialect-specific.

Comment: @darrenringer So how do mention the idea of watching a specific serial?

Comment: Pretty much like that... "I like to watch *a* serial", "if we are watching *a* comedy serial", etc.

Comment: @darrenringer  oh, it was a mistake in my question. I have just corrected it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct verb is "cracked", or simply "told" (to crack a joke = to tell a joke). But in this particular sentence it is best to leave out that verb, because it does not add any meaning, and it makes the sentence feel too wordy. Similarly, the use of the precise terms "family members" and "soap opera" makes the sentence feel overly scientific. More natural would be:

> I enjoy seeing my family laughing at the jokes on the show.

Note that one always laughs *at* things, never "on" them.

Also note the difference between "watch" and "see". To *watch* something means to deliberately stare at it, focusing your attention on it. To *see* something can be accidental. You watch the show, meaning that is your main focus, but you merely see your family around you, perhaps occasionally looking over at them. If you say that you "watch" your family, it suggests that you spend more time looking at them than at the television.

Comment: This is the more natural way of stating it. *laughing at the jokes in the show* would be better. Jokes are not **on** the show, they are **in** it.

Comment: Or in the case of _Big Bang Theory_ there are no jokes in the show, and the joke is on the audience. But I digress...

Answer (score 25):

**To play a (practical) joke**  versus **to crack a joke**.

To "play a (practical) joke", you **do** something that tricks a person. For example, exchanging salt for sugar, so that they put salt in their tea instead of sugar.

To "crack a joke" is to **say** something humorous to make people laugh, usually a brief remark or "one-liner".

We laugh **at** jokes, not **on** them.

Comment: So the correct sentence is: I enjoy watching my family members laughing at the jokes cracked in the soap opera.

Comment: @abhijeet pathak: I'm not familiar with funny soap-operas. In the ones you watch, are they playing tricks and practical jokes on each other, or saying funny things?

Comment: @abhijeetpathak While perfectly intelligible, that sounds awkward to my ear. As others have suggested 'laughing at the jokes in the show' sounds more natural.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo They are saying funny things. So as per your explanation **to crack a joke**  is applicable here.

Comment: @Strawberry I do agree that 'laughing at the jokes in the show' is more natural.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I have used the word soap operas, as I was looking for a synonym for TV serials. I found this word with meaning as follows on merriam-webseter:  a serial drama performed originally on a daytime radio or television program and chiefly characterized by tangled interpersonal situations and melodramatic or sentimental treatment. In that particular serial that I watch, the story revolves around the daily events of the members of a society. I think the famous comedy series **Friends** can also be called as a soap opera by this definition.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I hope hyphen added between soap and opera is a typo. Here soap is the adjective and opera is the noun, so there shouldn't any hyphen in between. Can you please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @abhijeet pathak: You should feel free to write it as two words or as a hyphenated word.  For many speakers, it has achieved compound status.  The genre tends to deal in melodrama not laughter. I believe fewer than 1% of native speakers of AmE would refer to *Friends* as a 'soap opera'. Most would call it a *sitcom* (situation comedy).